# Rails 5 vendor assets subdirectory not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to load a directory of assets from `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and it isn't working. It is a directory named `jaspersoft_theme`.

I thought that these files would be automatically loaded, as the `vendor/assets` path is, but it's not working.

I have also tried importing it in both my `main.scss` file and my `application.scss` file with no luck. I tried these combinations:

```
@import 'jaspersoft_theme';
@import 'jaspersoft_theme/*';
@import 'jaspersoft_theme/**/*';
```

Each time there was some variation of error saying that `jaspersoft_theme` is not a file.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the three `@import` lines at the same time? I think the first one could be wrong, if you delete that one there is still showing the error?

Comment: @DanielBatalla yeah, I've tried every combination!